# Hollow door repair and hook rehang

Tags: repair, doors

looking to see if it's feasible to repair a baseball sized hole in a hollow wooden door in a way that would allow a towel hook to be drilled onto it.

I've seen many guides for hollow door repair that follow the general order of stuffing newspapers, filling with insulation foam, covering with bondo/epoxy, then spackling paste before painting. Would this kind of repair be appropriate to then hang a hook attached with screws?

If not, what would be a better idea? Thank you for your time

Comment: How thick is the door where the hole is? A picture would be great.....

Comment: Thank you for the response Jack. It's a hollow wooden bathroom door, a hair under 1.5 inches thick where the hole is (ie not on a recessed panel).

Which I could upload a picture of the hole itself, but I've already tried the above method of repair and found that the repaired surface "sunk in" a little when drilling the pilot holes.

Comment: The reason why I wanted to know how thick the door was at the hole, was to determine if there was enough room to insert wood blocks to act as backer for a type of filler and for fastening the hook So the door is 1 3/8" thick where the hole is?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.